# Compiling Win64 versions of GLFW under mingw64

Tags: gcc, mingw, msys, glfw, mingw-w64

first off, I really need to make a 64bit version of glfwdll.a and glfw.dll (so I can hopefully finally succeed in getting the Go glfw bindings to work under Windows ... was a breeeeze under Linux!)

Seems like I now succeeded in compiling 64bit versions of glfwdll.a and glfw.dll using mingw64, MSYS and their make scripts, even though I did get a couple of error messages along the lines of "maincrt entry point not found, using default 0xsomehexnumber instead" or some such. Entry points of course refer to executables, in this case those in the examples directory.

And indeed, most of them don't work! All got built however. The following executables work:

listmodes.exe mtbench.exe mthello.exe and particles.exe -- the latter being the only graphical (3d gfx) example working for me (the former ones just outputting some test infos onto the console window).

Now what's the issue with the other ones? They don't crash, they don't report anything to the console... I run them, they return immediately, silently.

Is my GLFW build broken? How to fix? What's the big difference between the 4 examples that work and the others that don't?

This is a fairly new, vanilla Win7 64bit installation. No crapware, everything up to date, UAC and Themes are off, not a lot of software installed at all, Nvidia GPU driver updated (GPU Caps Viewer and the likes run fine, so OpenGL is there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not yet allowed to add comments, so I'll post this as an answer.

The issue you're having is due to three separate bug in GLFW. I fixed them today and the fixes will be included in GLFW 2.7.6. Until then, you can use trunk from the [GLFW Subversion repository](https://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=72569).

Comment: All works great now with the newest releases of Go, GLFW and Mingw-w64. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

To be sure that you really have no DLL-hell issues with the opengl32.dll, glu32.dll, glut32.dll etc., check out the Event Viewer tool and see if there are some warnings or errors for you app.

This is my thought because you are only able to run the mtbench and mthello which have nothing in common with the "real" OpenGL API.

No clue about particles.exe though - maybe GLFW checks for errors internally and call the exit() routine ? Check the %errorlevel% also.

Also take a look here:
http://glfw.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glfw/trunk/examples/pong3d.c?revision=1110&view=markup

There is a GameMenu() function which *may* exit silently if "!glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED )", which obviously means that OpenGL was *not* initialized.

The same function serves as an exit flag here
http://glfw.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glfw/trunk/examples/wave.c?revision=1110&view=markup

Once again, double-check the DLLs !

I believe that you are experienced not to make "advanced" mistakes in the build process, so there just might be some funny thing happening at the "user level".

And another suggestion:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/glfw/forums/forum/247562/topic/3868944

Some parameters might not work exactly for you.

To "fix" the samples try commenting out the glfwGetWindowParam call.

Comment: Actually my question was poorly chosen -- the real issue is that the build itself does not complete as intended. I do get entry-symbol warnings for all but the 4 mentioned examples. So no wonder they're not working. Also getting linker errors at the end of the make process, so although the libs do get built, they must be somewhat faulty builds to begin with. Following this up in a separate thread and filed an issue in GLFW's tracker. Thanks for those pointers though, useful knowledge in there nonetheless!

Comment: OK. Anyways, compiling/building with GCC flavours in Win32 is always close to nightmare :)  I never liked cygwin/msys myself :)

Comment: I'm overall really happy with Go but since they chose gcc for their C interop -- I have no choice about this part. :)

Comment: By the way particles.exe is the only (GUI) example app compiled/linked with -mconsole instead of -mwindows. Hence no entry-symbol issues here.